# 404 with React Router that I cannot reproduce locally

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm newbie with React and I have to fix a bug on a small static site, when I go to: https://sunchain.fr/en

it will gives me a 404 ( my page is hosted on gitlab pages, so you 404 has gitlab logo )

But when I go to http://localhost:3000/en , it works.

Here is the file where I define my links:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.css";
import logo from "../../media/svg/_LOGO_CONTOUR_BLANC.svg";

export const Header = ({
    linklogo,
    concept,
    autoconso,
    techno,
    appli,
    team,
    news,
    language
}) => (
    <div className="header">
        <div className="wrapper-header">
            <a href={linklogo} id="logo" className={logo}>
                &nbsp;
            </a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    {concept}
                    {autoconso}
                    {techno}
                    {appli}
                    {team}
                    {news}
                    {language}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
);

Header.propTypes = {
    concept: PropTypes.object,
    autoconso: PropTypes.object,
    techno: PropTypes.object,
    appli: PropTypes.object,
    team: PropTypes.object,
    news: PropTypes.object,
    language: PropTypes.object
};

export default Header;

export const HeaderFr = props => (
    <Header
        {...props}
        linklogo="/"
        concept={
            <a href="/#concept">
                <li>CONCEPT</li>
            </a>
        }
        autoconso={
            <a href="/#autoconsocoll">
                <li>AUTOCONSO</li>
            </a>
        }
        techno={
            <a href="/#techno">
                <li>TECHNO</li>
            </a>
        }
        appli={
            <a href="/#appli">
                <li>APPLICATIONS</li>
            </a>
        }
        team={
            <a href="/#team">
                <li>ÉQUIPE</li>
            </a>
        }
        news={
            <a href="/#news">
                <li>ACTUALITÉS</li>
            </a>
        }
        language={
            <Link to="/en">
                <li className="lang">ENGLISH</li>
            </Link>
        }
    />
);

export const HeaderEn = props => (
    <Header
        {...props}
        linklogo="/en"
        concept={
            <a href="/en#concept">
                <li>CONCEPT</li>
            </a>
        }
        autoconso={
            <a href="/en#autoconsocoll">
                <li>USE CASE</li>
            </a>
        }
        techno={
            <a href="/en#techno">
                <li>TECHNO</li>
            </a>
        }
        appli={
            <a href="/en#appli">
                <li>APPLICATIONS</li>
            </a>
        }
        team={
            <a href="/en#team">
                <li>TEAM</li>
            </a>
        }
        news={
            <a href="/en#news">
                <li>NEWS</li>
            </a>
        }
        language={
            <Link to="/">
                <li className="lang">FRANÇAIS</li>
            </Link>
        }
    />
);
```

I also defined my routes like that:

```
                <Route history={browserHistory} path="/en">
                    <HomeLayoutEn />
                </Route>
                <Route history={browserHistory} exact path="/">
                    <HomeLayoutFr />
                </Route>
```

Both version are the same, as I use Continuous Deployment to send it to production

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I navigate to https://sunchain.fr/, it loads fine. Then selecting 'english' to go to https://sunchain.fr/en/ works as well. The problem is performing a hard reload on this page will 404.

I suspect the issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually). Your app routing isn't able to persist on refresh, and you'll likely find a clear explanation/fix here.

Comment: yes, it seems to be the point. I tried to use BrowserHash but my tags in my one page site are not working anymore :(